# avr-gcc Arduino atmega2560 using far too much RAM

Tags: c, linker, arduino, avr-gcc, atmega

I'm currently trying to compile some code to work on AVR (ATMEGA2560) and it looks like I'm running out of RAM.

I looked at the listing (generated with `avr-objdump -x -S project.elf`) and I'm finding that `.data` is way too big to go into the 8kb RAM (it's around 12k) - in fact the 'real' RAM contents start at 0x802FEE which is in the address space for 'external RAM'.

I see:

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .data         00003088  00800200  0002297a  00022a0e  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  1 .text         0002297a  00000000  00000000  00000094  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  2 .bss          00000755  00803288  00803288  00025a98  2**2
                  ALLOC
  3 .stab         00001a7c  00000000  00000000  00025a98  2**2
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  4 .stabstr      00000d4d  00000000  00000000  00027514  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
```

I then grepped for `.data` symbols and sorted based on address:

```
grep "\.data" project.lst | sort
00800200 g       .data  00000000 __data_start
00800200 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
00802fee g     O .data  00000008 __thenan_sf
00802ff6 g     O .data  00000100 __clz_tab
008030f6 l     O .data  00000004 next
... lots of stuff in here ....
00803267 l     O .data  00000010 CSWTCH.18
00803277  w    O .data  00000010 _ZTV14HardwareSerial
00803288 g       .data  00000000 __data_end
00803288 g       .data  00000000 _edata
```

So `.data` is supposed to start at 0x800200, but for some reason the first symbol is at `00802fee` - which is well out of the address range.

I tried `-Wl,--section-start,.data=0x800000,--defsym=__heap_end=0x8021FF` but this only moves things back by `0x200` as expected - there's still something at the start of `.data` that is pushing everything out.

Does anyone know what this is, or why it's happening? It's annoying because everything should fit in if it weren't for that.

Comment: `.data` shall not go to Flash, but to RAM. And, no, you cannot just add external RAM without massive changes to your code. Did you forget making some variables `const`? `__clz_tab` sounds like that.

Comment: Yes, I know `.data` goes to RAM (my last question). However the problem is why .data starts with 11758 bytes (00802fee - 00800200) that don't seem to have any symbols to go with them.

Comment: It was a typo, which I just fixed. ATMEGA2560 has 256kB Flash, 8kB RAM. `.data` is too big for the RAM because it has 11758 unused bytes in it.

Comment: Check your map file.

Comment: Thanks - just did, and it's showing that each object file is using a bit of RAM in that area... But what for? There don't seem to be any symbols defined (at least that I can see)

Comment: Ok, it looks like it could be strings that are using up the RAM. They are un-named and so presumably don't get shown as symbols. But how do I get those put in flash? Defining *every string* as a variable with PROGMEM just isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @GordonWilliams depends on the code ... I did the following for debugging output (when simulating in `simavr`): https://github.com/Zirias/shuttercontrol/blob/master/shutterctl_attiny84/debug.h -- so in general, use `PSTR()` with literal constant strings

Comment: normally, gcc packs string literals into `.rodata` section and for von-Neumann Architectures, this is placed into read-only memory (Program Flash, if available). (One of the) problems with AVR is that this is Harvard Architecture and needs special code to access data in program memory, so you likely have to tag specially as `PROGMEM` seems to imply (until now, I could avoid to use such MCUs).

Comment: Thanks for your help - it looks like surrounding strings with PSTR removes that file's footprint in `.data`, so that's it. Wow, that's horrible. Such a shame there isn't a `-fput-consts-in-flash-yes-i-know-its-not-a-good-idea` flag in gcc.

Comment: Does someone want to post an answer to this, given it was anonymous strings/constants?

Comment: @GordonWilliams It must be done that way because you can't use "normal" string functions on data in program memory, they would try to access data memory. As @Olaf pointed out, on a Harvard architecture, there are different address spaces for program and data, and as C is designed with a von-Neumann architecture in mind with only one unified address space, a `char *` (or any pointer to data) in avr-gcc defaults to data address space.

Comment: Thanks - just accepted the answer. I guess it'd be possible to fake a flat address space by getting the compiler to convert all memory reads to `(p&0x80000000)?flash[p]:ram[p]` and to then optimise out for all the addresses it knows. It's a bit of a big ask though, and very nonoptimal in many cases :)

Comment: @GordonWilliams that's only possible if a) all accesses are in the same compilation unit and b) a function is always only called with *one* type of address. Otherwise you can't know which type of address is accessed at compile time.

Comment: @GordonWilliams: As I wrote, this is actually a matter of the linker control file, not gcc. gcc **does* privide all information required by the linker. problem is the AVR needs different (and much slower) code to acces such data. How should gcc know which `const` variables and literals to pack where? So you have to tell it, which apparently `PSTR` is for. Use a von-Neumann Architecture (S08/11/12, MSP430, ARM, etc.) and it works without manual intervention - provided the linker control file is correct.

Comment: "I guess it'd be possible ..." Yes, it would be possible. And render the code practially useless for any application on the architecture except for trivial stuff like tunring on an LED on a button press. Or it would make the linker become the actual compiler (perhaps with LTO), as much as @FelixPalmen wrote.

Comment: @Olaf just want to add the Harvard architecture is a good pick for the `avr` because with the two independent buses, the CPU can execute an instruction (that typically operates on data over one bus) while fetching the next one over the other bus, giving better performance here. The problem only arises with a language that's not aware of such an architecture :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen: The AVR architecture is a legacy like PIC (except PIC32 which is MIPS). All modern 32/64 bit architectures are actually a mixture of both concepts. They are von-Neumann from the instruction set, but Harvard in the CPU and various external busses (e.g. ARM-Cortex-M0+/3/4/7). For small MCUs, there are also better ways, which do not cost much more Silicon. Even less, as the AVR/PIC require additional logic for cross-accesses from internal data bus to Flash for self-programming and read-only data. Only benefit is program can reside in a full 16 (i.e. 2 octets) bit address space.

Comment: @Olaf, talking about these things, somehow "modified" harvard architectures are predominant everywhere, the question is just at which level the modifications kick in. I'm working with a very small and limited `avr` chip and for that, it feels quite natural, being a simple architecture giving the speed benefit of harvard in normal use. But continuing that, one might get into general hardware design discussions. The question just illustrates the backdraw in the programming model when using a language like C.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90516/discussion-between-olaf-and-felix-palmen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, OP already found out (with the help of Olaf's comments concerning where to start looking) what was actually taking up the space, but indeed, there should be an answer, so trying to summarize here:

1. The space in the data segment is also occupied by anonymous data (*literals* in code), especially *string literals*.
2. The tricky thing here is: `avr` is a *Harvard architecture* which means there are different/independent address spaces for code and data, contrary to the widespread *von Neumann architecture* with only one unified address space. [c](/questions/tagged/c) was designed for the latter, so it's only possible to handle one address space. On `avr` chips, the data address space is backed by *RAM*, the code address space by *flash memory*.

   Now, if running low on RAM, it would be sensible to place *read only* data in flash, too, but there's a catch: Given a function taking a `char *`, the compiler will translate this function assuming the pointer is meant to point to data address space and emit assembly fetching from there. Therefore, another similar function is needed that looks in code address space instead.
3. The solution in `avr-gcc` and `avr-libc` to this problem is to provide the `PROGMEM` qualifier, so the compiler knows data qualified this way should live in program memory (code address space). There's also a convenience macro `PSTR()` to make string literals live in program memory without the need to introduce another `PROGMEM`-qualified identifier. To work with these, `avr-libc` has a few standard functions postfixed `_P` (like, e.g., `puts_P()`) that do exactly the same, but expect their arguments in program memory. It's a bit of a hassle to use it that way, but it's just impossible to handle this transparently without [c](/questions/tagged/c) knowing about different address spaces.

As RAM is often quite small on `avr` chips, there are a few other things you can do to conserve it, like e.g. not using a heap at all (in many embedded programs, you don't really need dynamic allocation, just think about it), using bitfields where appropriate, have the compiler "pack" all structs (`-fpack-struct` option), always use the smallest possible size for enums (`-fshort-enums` option), always use `uint8_t` for small integers, use bitfields (or encode state with bit masking/shifting) where appropriate, and so on.